# Как вернуться на предыдущую страницу к определённому якорю на ней?

Tags: javascript

```
window.history.back ();
```

Этот метод возвращает на одну страницу назад в истории. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы возвращало не только на предыдущую страницу, но и к определённому якорю на предыдущей странице? (Без использования url страницы, просто используя имя якоря).
upd: Причём переход был не с якоря, а с произвольного места на предыдущей странице. А вернуться нужно именно к определённому якорю.

upd: Подсказали способ:

```
window.location = document.referrer + '#anchor';
```

Но почему-то в десктопном Хроме это работает не всегда. Вторая страница, с которой должен производиться возврат кнопкой на первую страницу, выдаёт в косноль, что для неё document.referrer - её собственный адрес, а не адрес первой страницы, с которой на неё был переход.

Подсказали ещё один способ, который тоже должен решить мою проблему, но уже с использованием url первой страницы. В этом url есть utm метки, которые могут быть разными. Поэтому, нужен был способ возврата на первую страницу без использования url. Но подсказали сделать так. На первой странице записать utm переменную из url в localStorage, а на второй странице взять её оттуда и вписать в url, на который нужно вернуться (и прибавить якорь). Работает, но тоже не всегда. В десктопном Хроме снова проблема. Первая страница записывает в localStorage элемент со значением "а", вторая страница получает из localStorage значение "а". Первая страница стрирает этот элемент и снова записывает его с тем же ключом и со значением "b", вторая страница снова считывает значение "a". Непонятно вообще. Где в Хроме кэшируются данные из localStorage кроме самого localStorage?

upd2:
Разобралась, почему одна страница сайта не видела в localStorage то, что в него записала другая. Оказывается, при изменении вручную utm меток в адресной строке Хром меняет сам http на https. И для страниц сайта с http одно хранилище, а с https другое.

У меня теперь всё работает, вопрос можно считать закрытым.